# Why is music compressed with lossy codecs down to low bitrates in modern games?

Tags: audio, compression

I wonder why anyone would compress the soundtrack of a game with lossy codecs (mp3 mainly) down to 128 kbps bitrate. Thing is I see it on most of the games. Rarely a game has 320 kbps soundtrack, let alone lossless audio formats. It's mostly the case when a game is delivered digitally with a soundtrack packed as DLC along with the main game, and still sometimes the game itself uses a lossy version of it, which just seems silly.

It might have been an issue of free hard drive space or insufficient CD capacity, but these days games are either shipped on huge multiple-layered high capacity optical discs, or fully delivered via content distribution networks.

Why do modern games have lossy encoded music files?

Comment: File size, perhaps?

Comment: @ShotgunNinja when the game is delivered digitally? Don't you think that would be irrelevant today?

Comment: @MickLH I'm not even talking about the frequencies most people can't hear and most headsets can't produce, but about the recognizable mpegy noises due to such low target quality compression. That's just bad. You can't justify that. It's like saying "no player would care anyway".

Comment: How is this anything but a rant? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: This question is worded with too much opinion to be genuinely seeking a logical answer.  But it does have practical, fact-based answers, and Sean already provided one.  So it gets that rare downvote-sans-closevote from me.

Comment: @JoshPetrie the problem was I didn't know why developers decide to do that. Now that I have a nice accepted answer with some reasons I agree with, the problem is solved. If the question doesn't fit the site enough that you would like to remove it, please go ahead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Larger sizes cost money and slow down downloads.  That matters.  When you have a game that has multiple music tracks compressing down lossily can save many megabytes (even gigabytes if you include audio effects, dialog, etc).  Sure, your game might already be a 4GB download, but why pay for extra server bandwidth and make users wait longer for 5GB if there's no benefit to doing so?  Especially as we move more into free-to-play: a game that downloads in 5 minutes has a much higher chance of converting players (and making more money) than one that takes 7 minutes to download.  Every single last barrier between catching a potential player's interest and getting him in game needs to be broken down if possible.  See the success of Flash games and their very fast "click link to game's site, be in game" conversion opportunities.

Then let's think about platforms that have limited storage size.  A console might only have several GB available for user downloaded games on limited flash memory.  An 800MB title will fit.  A 2GB+ title will only be available to a subset of console owners.

Now let's look at memory.  If you need to load music, sound effects, and dialog into memory to play it, what do you do on a system like the 360 that only has 512MB shared with the video card in total?  Even on PC, many users are still on a 32-bit OS, which means you've got all of 2GB (maybe 3) to fit everything you need loaded on the CPU, including audio.  For music only this is somewhat reduced since you're usually streaming, but the compressed audio still allows smaller buffers (assuming you're offloading to an audio unit that can decompress on its own) in main memory.  The streaming is also less likely to lag or glitch with smaller, less-frequent requests for blocks achieved by packing in more audio data in less space.

And then of course there's other considerations like mobile games, where you need to keep the entire game under ~50MB in order to be able to be downloaded on cellular connections.  A player who finds your game on the bus but can't download is probably not going to bother looking up your game again later when they get home: you've missed your chance to get a new customer.  You need to get the entire game - executables, packaging, textures, models, game data, and audio - into that 50MB envelope.

These other platforms affect the PC indirectly, too.  There needs to be a strong case to spend the time and money to write two different audio conversion pipelines for PC and consoles (and then test them), and "the PC can do it better" is not generally a strong case for most titles (since making the PC version better rarely increases sales signifiicantly).  If you're already converting to MP3 or Ogg to deal with a console, you might as well just reuse all that pipeline work and verification on the PC.

Comment: I can agree with the "sale points" aspects, but not necessarily the rest.

Comment: The last paragraph deserves better billing.  Making an awesomely produced soundtrack especially for audiophiles doesn't improve the bottom line.  So any studio that conceivable could put resources into such audio would (almost) always elect not to.

Answer (score 1):

Many players would care a lot if their download times suddenly doubled, making an impulse purchase less likely.  Also, I don't know if this still holds true, but for digital/marketplace options some devices (xbox?) had a tight upper limit on size.

And someone, somewhere, pays for that bandwidth.

Plus runtime RAM limits are seen as better spent on graphics, which are immediately obvious to 99% of all players and reviewers, versus audio which is only noticed if it's either out of sync or has really bad voice actors.

Comment: Why double? A big title game usually takes up several gigabytes of disk space. Music is about 200-300 megabytes. If that doubles, the overall space consumed will increase only maybe 10%. But that's usually even less with visuals-heavy modern games, which take up several tens of gigabytes of space.

Comment: It should be noted that many (if not all) audio decoding libraries don't cache the whole file at a time, but read chunks from disk to save RAM. I'm sure this tech has been around since 90's. So I don't really see how it would seriously damage RAM consumption *or* hard drive space.

Comment: Sorry, was working on an audio-heavy title for a little while and shouldn't have used 2x as a general rule, more of a "it could possibly be this bad" scenario.  Other than that, since the original question didn't mention large AAA titles I set up my answer for small independent ventures which are often way less heavy on graphics.